# Math.random not properly working in the code

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Raffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of partcipants ");
        int no=scan.nextInt();
        String participants[]=new String[no];
        System.out.println("Please enter their names and check out the random winner");
        for(int i=0;i<no;i++) {
            participants[i]=scan.next();
        }
        int rand=(int)Math.random()*no;
        System.out.println(rand);
        System.out.println("The winner of the raffle is "+participants[rand]);
    }
}
```

I used `Math.random()` but I see during run that always the 0 index position is giving the result and not the random value. Any suggestions?  I am on eclipse oxygen.

Comment: the fact that you assume that the version of your ide is even remotely relevant here, says quite a lot. what do you mean "the result, not the random value"?

Comment: Yeah i know its not much relavent just added extra info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are casting the result of `Math.random()` to `int` prior to multiplying it by `no`, which results in `0`, since `Math.random() < 1.0`.

Change

```
int rand=(int)Math.random()*no;
```

to

```
int rand=(int)(Math.random()*no);
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting a double between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive) will always round down to zero. A Math.random() value should first be multiplied with some factor before casting it to an int to get a value between zero (inclusive) and the multiplication factor (exclusive). Another possible solution would be to use the nextInt() method of java.util.Random.